# C++ - Convert class to other types

Tags: c++, class, casting

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class length
{
 int meter;
public:
 length(int m)
 {
  meter=m;
 }
 operator double()
 {
  return (1.0*meter/1000);
 }
};
int main()
{
 length a(1500);
 double m=double(a);
double n=float(a);
double l=int(a);
 cout <<"m="<<m<<"km"<<endl;
 cout <<"m="<<n<<"km"<<endl;
 cout <<"m="<<l<<"km"<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
m=1.5km
m=1.5km
m=1km
```

Why does `float(a)` and `int(a)` work with only `double(Class length)` defined ?

Comment: You should avoid `using namespace...` especially in a header. It can cause namespace collisions with other sources. You could do `using std::cout;` though.

Comment: @C.Lang I know this. This is just a extremely simple test code snippet. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float` and `int` work because C++ has built-in conversions among numeric types. In particular, the `double` can be converted to `float` and to `int`; that is what's happening in your program: the conversion of `length` to `double` is performed with your user-defined conversion operator, and then the built-in conversion from `double` to `float` or `int` is performed to coerce the type to the desired target type.